# Add Views Programatically with loop, First Element is not shown

Tags: java, android, horizontal-scrolling

i loop through an array of objects and add a custom view with the objects name to a horizontalscrollview for each. My problem is, that the first one always disappears.

Here is my Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="lp.german.bischofshofpresenter.app.PraesentationsActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Hier wird das pdf gezeigt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/file_scroll_view"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/file_scroll_view_linear_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I fill the LinearLayout with the following Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.file_template, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.file_template_text);
        textView.setText(files[i].Name());
        Log.v("FILENAME:",files[i].Name());
        View fileList = findViewById(R.id.file_scroll_view_linear_layout);
        ((ViewGroup)fileList).addView(v, ((ViewGroup)fileList).getChildCount());
    }
```

I get the following result:

[image]

First Objects name is File0, so this one is missing.
The really strange thing is, that there is an empty space on the right side that matches exactly the size of one of my elements.

See here:

[image]

I already checked with the Log output, that it loops through all 10 elements and its there, so I can
t explain that behaviour.

What might be the fault is the position I set in `((ViewGroup)fileList).addView(v, ((ViewGroup)fileList).getChildCount());` but i don't know whats wrong here.

Thanks in forward ;)

Comment: simply use `addView(View v)` and see what happens.

Comment: and add the full screen image without cutting anything out

Comment: the image is not the problem, it's just a placeholder...tried simply with view as i said, but still same behaviour...